# Laravel upload via FTP prevent overriding live logs

Tags: laravel, ftp

I am updating my laravel project via FTP.

I set override all files, where edit date changed.

**Problem:**

It overrides the live logs with the dev logs, because the name of the log file is the same.

I wanted to change log names (could save it in .env, because live project has its own .env), but I have not found a way to do it.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude logs file/dir when copying files instead of overriding it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

Go to `logging.php` and edit this condig:

```
'single' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    //'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
    'path' => storage_path(env('LOG_PATH')),
    'level' => 'debug',
],

'daily' => [
    'driver' => 'daily',
    //'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
    'path' => storage_path(env('LOG_PATH')),
    'level' => 'debug',
    'days' => 14,
]
```

Because the live project has a different `.env`, you can define a different folder or filename and it will work.